# how to combine status bar and toolbar with gradient in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

[I want to combine status bar and toolbar with gradient like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx42I.png)

I have tried to set status bar transparent and make the toolbar big and set the gradient . 
But It also makes your UI goes under the Soft navigation keys.

And also soft keyboard is covering the EditTexts.
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" not working

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
     Window window = Window;
     window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
     window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentNavigation);
}
```

Is there any way only the status bar make transparent rather than transparent both status bar and navigation button on the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alse do like this,add the code into the `OnCreate` method :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

  if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Kitkat)
    {
      Window w = Window;
      w.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
      w.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden|SoftInput.AdjustResize);
    }
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_other);
 }
```

then create the **gradient.xml** in **Resources/drawable** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <gradient android:angle="135" 
               android:startColor="#f56f2c" 
               android:endColor="#fa9f46"/>
 </shape>
```

at last in the **layout.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation = "vertical"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:fitsSystemWindows= "true"
              android:background= "@drawable/gradient"
           >

   <!--use Toolbar-->
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:title="标题"
      app:titleTextColor="#fff"
      app:subtitle="副标题"
      app:subtitleTextColor="#fff"/>

   <!--if dont use Toolbar,RePresent Toolbar-->
   <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="44dp">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_width="35dp"
          android:layout_height="35dp" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:textSize="25sp"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textColor="#fff"
          android:text="Test Title"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fillViewport="true"
          android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
          android:background = "#fff" //set the background color of your content
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation ="vertical" >
         <!--your content -->
           ...
     </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But It makes  UI goes under the Soft navigation keys.

Comment: Then Navigation bar color not changed I tried with to add flags   w.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
w.SetNavigationBarColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorWhite));

Comment: i run it fine,could you show me the screenshots of “ UI goes under the Soft navigation keys”

Comment: and when you start type also soft keyboard is covering the EditTexts.http://prntscr.com/mpbr3g

Comment: First, i think "UI goes under the Soft navigation keys" just because it was set `w.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentNavigation);` to make the navigation bar transparent bar ,you could try to delete this line to have a look. Second,the issue of keyboard ，you should set `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan` or nested layer of scrollview

Comment: I have already set WindowSoftInputMode to adjustpan.And let me remove to flag

Comment: Still same problem.Now,What can I do ?

Comment: issue one or two ?

Comment: both issues still

Comment: protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Kitkat)
            {
                Window w = Window;
          
                 w.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
                 w.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
             
            }
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SignUpProfileDetailsViewLayout);
            Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);
       
        }

Comment: issue one : try it with delete this line "w.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentNavigation);"

Comment: issue two ,i will check it for you tomorrow ,the computer doesn't work today.

Comment: I have alreday remove it.I set trancluentstatus also.Still same issue.

Comment: i have update the answer,and you could have a try ,if dont work ,please show me your xaml code then i could check for you~

Comment: but If I have to add a image background then ??? and also I want to add snackbar like layout like this http://prntscr.com/mqgc9j  then ??

Comment: Just set the image or color to the background of ScrollView ! I only check Toast,i think snackbar could work also,you could have a try .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the color of status bar same as the startColor of gradient and let the toolbar start from where it does.

Comment: I want to set gradient and combine with it.I want to looks it seamless.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static method that sets the status bar colour something like below:

```
 public static void SetStatusBarGradiant(Activity activity)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            Window window = activity.Window;
            Drawable background = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(activity.Resources, Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha, null);
            window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
            window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            window.SetBackgroundDrawable(background);
        }
    }
```

Then add a `gradient.xml` in drawable something like below see to it you set the start color and end color as per your requirement:

**gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
   <shape>
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#FF00FF00"
        android:type="linear" />
   </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Goodluck

Revert if you have queries

Comment: If I set to separate gradient to status bar then it's looks different with toolbar.

Comment: Then use the same gradients xml in place of my gradient

Comment: How to set one gradient(same) for toolbar and status bar combined.